# Ubuntu 14.04: Using Bluetooth Dongle, not detecting any device

Tags: 14.04, bluetooth

I have tried it on Windows and it is working perfectly, so there is no issue with the device.

I have also tried different solutions I could find like trying to check if there is a soft/hard block, installing Bluetooth manager but to no avail.

I currently have Ubuntu 14.04.5 LTS. Thank you.

Here is the output of lsusb command:

```
Bus 001 Device 004: ID 0bda:8179 Realtek Semiconductor Corp. RTL8188EUS 802.11n Wireless Network Adapter
Bus 001 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0002 Linux Foundation 2.0 root hub
Bus 005 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 004 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 003 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
Bus 002 Device 003: ID 09da:c10a A4Tech Co., Ltd. 
Bus 002 Device 002: ID 0a12:0001 Cambridge Silicon Radio, Ltd Bluetooth Dongle (HCI mode)
Bus 002 Device 001: ID 1d6b:0001 Linux Foundation 1.1 root hub
```

Comment: Please [edit] your question and add output of `lsusb` terminal command. What release are you using now?

Answer (score 0):

Not all dongles are supported. Try this in terminal:

```
sudo apt-get install bluez-utils
sudo /etc/init.d/bluez-utils restart
lsusb
```

if it is recognized and appropriate it should show up here, you can paste the output in reply if confused.

Comment: It put all commands in one line when i posted for some reason, 3 seperate commands to issue: (sudo apt-get install bluez-utils) (sudo /etc/init.d/bluez-utils restart) (lsusb)

Comment: [Here](http://paste.ubuntu.com/25346941/) is the output of all three commands.

Comment: If you now type: 'hcitool scan' can you see your bluetooth devices]

Comment: Sorry, still not detecting.

Comment: If you see in the output I posted above, the output of the second command is "sudo: /etc/init.d/bluez-utils: command not found". Does this mean something is wrong?

Comment: try '/etc/init.d/bluetooth restart' then once again the 'hcitool scan'

Comment: Here is the result:

stop: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.89" (uid=1000 pid=4342 comm="stop bluetooth ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Stop" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")
start: Rejected send message, 1 matched rules; type="method_call", sender=":1.90" (uid=1000 pid=4336 comm="start bluetooth ") interface="com.ubuntu.Upstart0_6.Job" member="Start" error name="(unset)" requested_reply="0" destination="com.ubuntu.Upstart" (uid=0 pid=1 comm="/sbin/init")

Comment: It seems like your bluetooth package is bugged or wont start.  check status - '/etc/init.d/bluetooth status'

Comment: Here is the result: 'bluetooth start/running, process 436'.

Comment: I just tried this command after turning bluetooth off from top bar but the status command still says 'bluetooth start/running, process 436'. I tried to kill this process from 'htop' command but it does not kill. It shows that this process uses the command '/usr/sbin/bluetoothd'.

Comment: If it won't let you restart the service, see if you can force stop and start it again. If it still won't recognize any available devices you'll have to start digging in logs. Info on that can be found here https://wiki.ubuntu.com/DebuggingBluetooth sorry I couldn't be of more help. Upgrading may or may not help with this specific device.

Comment: I will try that link. Thank you for your help.